# Use specific system user for wso2 esb service invocation

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am going to have a web portal from which I will be calling services with "UsernameToken" security.

For authentication purposes I would like to create a system user in the wso2 Identity Server, so that I can use it to call the services from the ESB. So basically, I want to request a token for the system user from the WSO2 Identity Server and use it to authenticate infront WSO2 ESB so I can call the services.

I plan to use the AuthenticationAdmin and UserAdmin services for the authentication.

Is this scenario possible? If not what would be a good way to achieve similar scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your requirement properly, I assume, you're trying to call a set of backend services via WSO2 ESB having "UsernameToken" as the authentication pattern. If that's so, then I don't see any requirement for you to use WSO2 IS for user creation, unless you're planning to do much deeper Identity Management.(You can still use it but I consider it as sort of an overhead given the fact that you just want to create the users there in WSO2 IS). For this, you can use the user management capabilities embedded in the WSO2 ESB (or in any other WSO2 product). What you would simply have to do is, create a user at the ESB level and use those credentials to call the backend services via the ESB.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Prabath. I however have to use the Identity Server because this scenario will be part of a bigger project. I've managed to solve my problem they way you suggested though!